# Assign image from a folder to blog post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a bunch of images in a folder, how can I display 1 image per post on a wordpress blog, the image can be chosen at random (or not, doesn't matter), but once displayed, it should always stay assigned to the blog post, and each blog post should get assigned a different image until the folder runs out of images, then it should circle back.

Comment: Check out this link, which should set you on your way to building a custom function to do exactly what you're after: http://wpforce.com/automatically-set-the-featured-image-in-wordpress/

Comment: ¿How are the posts published? ¿One by one in a single page, some or all of them in a page? ¿Do they belong to a special category? Please provide more information.

Comment: i ended up using a hash key with strlen of the content and modulo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set image for post, you can also add custom field to your post and set its name to thumb.